# Embedding 'show' segues in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, interface-builder

In this simplified example I have:

1. TabBarController (initial view controller) with two items
2. ViewContainer in the 1st item
3. ViewController1 that embedded in the View Container
4. Button in ViewController1
5. ViewController2 connected with show segue to the button
   [image]

When I click the button, the tab bar of the Tab Bar Controller is disappearing but I want it to be presented and be able to navigate to Item 2 even after clicking the button. What is the right way to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding, whenever you *navigate* from a controller in the *first tab*, you would still like to have the ability to select tab 2 from the tab bar.

For this you can make the `ViewController` in the first tab to be embedded inside a `UINavigationViewController`. Now whenever you'll push a new controller, your tab bar will still be visible allowing you to switch to other tab.

Hope my understanding of your problem was correct.